# why the event-source-polyfill did not fetch the sse api data

Tags: reactjs, rust, server-sent-events

I have defined a sse api on the server side using rust like this:

```
use actix_web::{App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, post, get};
use rust_wheel::common::util::net::sse_stream::SseStream;
use std::time::{Duration, SystemTime};
use tokio::{
    sync::mpsc::{UnboundedReceiver, UnboundedSender},
    task,
};

#[get("/sse/producer")]
pub async fn sse() -> impl Responder {
    let (tx, rx): (UnboundedSender<String>, UnboundedReceiver<String>) =
        tokio::sync::mpsc::unbounded_channel();
    task::spawn(async move {
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let message = format!("Current time: {:?}", SystemTime::now());
            tx.send(message).unwrap();
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        }
    });
    let response = HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/event-stream")
        .streaming(SseStream { receiver: Some(rx) });
    response
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(sse).service(sse))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8000")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

this is the `Cargo.toml` dependencies:

```
tokio = { version = "1.17.0", features = ["full"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", branch = "diesel2.0" }
actix-web = "4"
```

using curl to test the api:

```
curl -N http://localhost:8000/sse/producer
```

it works fine. Then I defined the client using `"event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.31"` like this to fetch the sse data:

```
import React from 'react';
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'event-source-polyfill';

const App: React.FC = () => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    doSse();
  },[]);

  const doSse = () => {
    let eventSource: EventSourcePolyfill;    
    eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill('/sse/producer', {
      headers: {
      }
    });
    eventSource.onopen = () => {
      
    }
    eventSource.onerror = (error:any) => {
      console.log(error)
      eventSource.close();
    }
    eventSource.onmessage = (msg: any) => {
      console.log(msg)
    };
  }

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

nothing returned.  Am I missing something? what should I do to make it work? this is the client proxy config:

```
proxy: {
      '/sse': 'http://localhost:8000/'
    }
```

the client log shows this message:

[image]

I could not get any useful message. Any suggestion is appreciate. I also tried to change the event source data to standard format like this:

```
#[get("/sse/producer")]
pub async fn sse() -> impl Responder {
    let (tx, rx): (UnboundedSender<SSEMessage>, UnboundedReceiver<SSEMessage>) =
        tokio::sync::mpsc::unbounded_channel();
    task::spawn(async move {
        for _ in 0..5 {
            let message:SSEMessage = SSEMessage::from_data(&"data11".to_string(),&"TEX_LOG".to_string());
            tx.send(message).unwrap();
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        }
    });
    let response = HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/event-stream")
        .streaming(SseStream { receiver: Some(rx) });
    response
}
```

this is how the `SSEMessage` defined:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct SSEMessage {
    pub event: Option<String>,
    pub data: String,
    pub id: Option<String>,
    pub retry: Option<u32>,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some deep research I found the polyfill using the fetch to do the sse request, seems the google chrome did not treat the polyfill as a event source request, so did not show in the event stream list in devtools. more info: https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource/issues/79
https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource/issues/94